# How to integrate offline maps in Ionic+Angular using leaflet maps?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, leaflet, openstreetmap, offline

```
this.map = leaflet.map("mapId", { zoomControl: false }).setView([17.385, 78.4867], 13);
      leaflet.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
        attribution: '',
      }).addTo(this.map);
      this.map.locate({
        setView: true,
        maxZoom: 11
      })
```

We have tried implementing the above code. It is working fine in online mode but does not work when offline. How can we implement current location & search locations functionality in leaflet maps when offline? Anyone who integrated offline leaflet maps with Ionic + Angular, please provide a solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So let's clear things. If you want an offline map in Angular with Ionic
[READ THIS BLOG POST](https://blog.bam.tech/developer-news/how-to-build-an-offline-map-system-for-an-hybrid-app)

Then if you want an implementation of the current location you should use
[Geolocation Cordova Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation)
and as they say :

> This plugin provides information about the device's location, such as latitude and longitude. Common sources of location information include **Global Positioning System (GPS)** and location inferred from network signals such as IP address, RFID, WiFi, and Bluetooth MAC addresses, and GSM/CDMA cell IDs.

To search locations by name fragment
You should store the locations name in the database with the corresponding pair of coordinates
like

```
// KEY : NAME OF LOCATION : VALUE [LATITUDE, LONGITUDE]
object: {[key: string]:[number,number] } = {"USA":[37.6000,-95.6650]};
```

then you will be able to search coordinates by their location name.

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for your quick reply. But we want solution in Ionic + Angular.

Comment: May we can't provide you a fully functional solution to this. But with a little refactoring, you can grab that code and use it in Angular. But I'm on it and I try to dynamically update my Answer

Comment: http://davidrs.com/wp/phonegap-3-0-leaflet-offline-maps/
Unfortunately, this demo is not working for us and showing 404 error for images.